# Is Set, the category of sets, a self-dual category?

Tags: category-theory

Because **Rel**, the category of relations, is self-dual, and because **Rel** has **Set**, the category of sets, as a subcategory, can we conclude that **Set** itself is self-dual? And, just as **Rel** is a dagger category, is **Set** also a dagger category?

Comment: Why should a subcategory of a self-dual category be self-dual? (It shouldn't: e.g. every small category is isomorphic to a subcategory of **Rel**.)

Answer (score 8):

No, $\text{Set}$ and $\text{Set}^{op}$ differ in many ways. One of the simpler ones is that $\text{Set}$ is a [distributive category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/distributive+category): finite products distribute over finite coproducts. This is very false in $\text{Set}^{op}$, as can already be seen for finite sets. Another is that $\text{Set}$ is [generated](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/separator) by its terminal object; this is again very false in $\text{Set}^{op}$.