# What is the name of a category $A$ for which $A \simeq A^{op}$?

Tags: category-theory

Any discrete category is a trivial example. The connected category $2$ is also.

Does it have a name ?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_(category_theory)) says *self-dual*.

Comment: looks like an answer ! thank you

Comment: Alos this site has several posts confirming this, e.g., [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2997008/is-set-the-category-of-sets-a-self-dual-category).

Comment: For reference, there are some interesting links here about self-duals https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92355/what-is-a-self-dual-category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, an applicable name is "self-dual."